# Symfony 4: Webpack Encore - call method in other JS file

Tags: symfony, webpack

I want to call within the `index.js` file a method from `app.js`. But I get the error `app.test is not a function`. Snippet from my `webpack.config.js`:

```
Encore
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('index', './assets/js/index.js')
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .createSharedEntry('vendor', [
       './assets/js/vendor/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js'
    ])
   .autoProvideVariables({
       $: 'jquery',
       jQuery: 'jquery',
       'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
   });
```

`app.js` contains only the `test` method:

```
function test() {
    return "test123";
}
```

and `index.js`tries to call this method:

```
let app = require("./app");

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log(app); // empty object {}
    console.log(app.test());
});
```

What is wrong with this setup? Did I misunderstood the concept of webpack? I thought it is possible to require the needed modules and access them like in the example above.

Comment: Did you run `yarn run encore dev --watch` see https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#configuring-encore-webpack if Yes, check that the app.js is created in web/js

Comment: I'm running only `encore dev --watch` which works fine, the `app.js` and `index.js` are generated under `public/build`.

Comment: The generated `index.js`contains the following code: https://pastebin.com/3P8PvDty . So the `app.js` was required successfully, however calling the `test()` method does not work.

Comment: I'm not a JS expert but could you try to change `let app` by `var app` please ?

Comment: That doesn't matter, it's translated to "plain" JavaScript as you can see in the pastebin posted above (`var appTest = ...`).

Comment: I think there is a problem with the variable scope https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav

Comment: Hmm, `var app = require("./app");` still does not work, same error message and the generated `index.js` is identical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, your modules are related, so you should only use 1 js entry. Remove your `app.js` entry in `webpack.config.js`.
Next in your app.js, export your function

```
function test() {
    return "test123";
}

module.exports = {
    test
};
```

In your index.js

```
let app = require("./app");

$(document).ready(function () {
    app.test()
});
```

Or an alternative approach using ESM modules:

app.js

```
export function test() {
    return "test123";
}
```

index.js

```
import { test } from './app';

$(document).ready(function () {
    test();
});
```